# How to show there are irreducible polynomials of any degree over $\Bbb Z _p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I show there are irreducible polynomials of any degree in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, with $p$ prime?

I tried counting the number of reducible polynomials of any degree but that turned out to be hard... Any help?

Comment: You are on the right track.  You can count the monic polynomials of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ and subtract the ones that have a factor of degree at most $n/2$.  What remains is the number of irreducible polynomials there of degree $n$.

Comment: Wouldn't I be double counting?

Comment: See [Existence of irreducible polynomials over finite field](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144703/existence-of-irreducible-polynomials-over-finite-field), and [Existence of an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285778/existence-of-an-irreducible-polynomial-over-mathbb-f-p), and [Lack of understanding of the proof of the existence of an irreducible polynomial of any degree $n \ge 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125854/lack-of-understanding-of-the-proof-of-the-existence-of-an-irreducible-polynomial).

Comment: I cannot understand the third link and the rest uses things I haven't proven yet. Could you explain what you meant by counting?

Comment: Have a look at [Find the number of irreducible polynomials in any given degree](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792674/find-the-number-of-irreducible-polynomials-in-any-given-degree), which tackles the difficulty of exactly counting the irreducible monic polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ of degrees 2 and 3.  However an exact count is not required in order to prove existence; we only need a positive count!

Comment: Wait but I already tried this, you need to keep track of the amount of irreducibles of any degree and it doesn't work out nicely...

Comment: Do you know the fact that $X^{p^n} - X$ is the product of all irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ whose degree divides $n$?  [This Answer by Marc van Leeuwen](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288120/existence-of-irreducible-polynomial-of-arbitrary-degree-over-finite-field-withou/288183#288183) leverages that fact to show at least one irreducible polynomial of degree exactly $n$ exists.